# Getting JSON data from google maps with swift 3

Tags: ios, json, google-maps, swift3

I am currentll on an ios swift 3 application project that use google maps data with JSON, but when I start compiling, I can't get the value of ["results"]:

```
if let results = dic["results"] as? JSONDictionary {
                                print(results)
                            }
```

While dict contain this:

```
["results": <__NSSingleObjectArrayI 0x155d73c0>(
{
    "address_components" =     (
                {
            "long_name" = Paris;
            "short_name" = Paris;
            types =             (
                locality,
                political
            );
        },
                {
            "long_name" = Paris;
            "short_name" = Paris;
            types =             (
                "administrative_area_level_2",
                political
            );
        },
                {
            "long_name" = "\U00cele-de-France";
            "short_name" = "\U00cele-de-France";
            types =             (
                "administrative_area_level_1",
                political
            );
        },
                {
            "long_name" = France;
            "short_name" = FR;
            types =             (
                country,
                political
            );
        }
    );
    "formatted_address" = "Paris, France";
    geometry =     {
        bounds =         {
            northeast =             {
                lat = "48.9021449";
                lng = "2.4699209";
            };
            southwest =             {
                lat = "48.815573";
                lng = "2.225193";
            };
        };
        location =         {
            lat = "48.856614";
            lng = "2.3522219";
        };
        "location_type" = APPROXIMATE;
        viewport =         {
            northeast =             {
                lat = "48.9021449";
                lng = "2.4699209";
            };
            southwest =             {
                lat = "48.815573";
                lng = "2.225193";
            };
        };
    };
    "place_id" = ChIJD7fiBh9u5kcRYJSMaMOCCwQ;
    types =     (
        locality,
        political
    );
}
)
, "status": OK]
```

While JSONDictionary = [String:Any]

What is the problem here? Thanks.

Comment: Your results is an array and not a dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cast the outer JSON as a [String: Any] so would be done the following way:

Assuming that the dic you have casted as `[String: Any]` then proceed by casting the contents of results value, which is an Array.

```
if let results = dic["results"] as? Array<Any> {
    print(results)
}
```

Then you should be able to print and abstract the JSON further.